# Update database from view

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

View.py

```
@login_required
def UnosPosudbe(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        forma = PosudbaForma()
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        forma = PosudbaForma(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if forma.is_valid():
            #Dohvacanje Kolicine
            kolicinaKnjige = str(forma.cleaned_data['nazivKnjige'])
            IDKnjige = kolicinaKnjige

            kolicinaKnjige = kolicinaKnjige[-1:]
            IDKnjige = IDKnjige[:1]

            unesenaKolicina = forma.cleaned_data['kolicina']
            if(int(kolicinaKnjige)>=unesenaKolicina and unesenaKolicina > 0):
                #update kolicine
                knjiga = Knjiga.objects.get(pk=IDKnjige)
                knjiga.kolicina = int(knjiga.kolicina) - int(unesenaKolicina)
                print(knjiga)
                knjiga_forma = KnjigaForma(request.POST, instance = knjiga)
                knjiga_forma.save() 
                #
                forma.save()
                return redirect('pregledPosudbe')
    return render(request, 'unosPosudbe.html', {'forma':forma})
```

I am trying to update database with part of code but I am keep getting error:

```
knjiga = Knjiga.objects.get(pk=IDKnjige)
                knjiga.kolicina = int(knjiga.kolicina) - int(unesenaKolicina)
                print(knjiga)
                knjiga_forma = KnjigaForma(request.POST, instance = knjiga)
                knjiga_forma.save()
```

Error:

> ValueError at /UnosPosudbe/ The Knjiga could not be changed because
>   the data didn't validate.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong?

Models.py

```
class Knjiga(models.Model):
    naziv = models.CharField(null=False, blank=True, max_length=120)
    autor = models.ForeignKey(Autor, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)   
    datumObjave = models.DateField(null=True, blank=False)
    izdanje = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=120)
    slika= models.FileField(upload_to='images/', null=True, verbose_name="") #videofile
    kolicina = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id) + ', ' +str(self.naziv) + ', ' + str(self.autor) + ', Kolicina:' + str(self.kolicina)
```

-----UPDATE----

Everything works for above problem.
But now I want to do when I delete created line that it gets quantity back to my "knjiga.kolicina".

Delete works like:

@login_required
def deletePosudbe(request, id):
    data = Posudba.objects.get(id=id)

```
IDKnjige = data
kolicinaKnjige = IDKnjige[-1:]
IDKnjige = IDKnjige[:1]

print(kolicinaKnjige)
print(IDKnjige)

data.delete()
return redirect('pregledPosudbe')
```

I get error:

> TypeError at /deletePosudbe/22 'Posudba' object is not subscriptable

I am trying to do same to fetch ID and quantity and update it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is validation of `KnjigaForma(request.POST, instance=knjiga)` ? you need it...

```
from django.db.models import F
@login_required
def UnosPosudbe(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        forma = PosudbaForma()
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        forma = PosudbaForma(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if forma.is_valid():
            #Dohvacanje Kolicine
            kolicinaKnjige = str(forma.cleaned_data['nazivKnjige'])
            IDKnjige = kolicinaKnjige

            kolicinaKnjige = kolicinaKnjige[-1:]
            IDKnjige = IDKnjige[:1]

            unesenaKolicina = forma.cleaned_data['kolicina']
            if(int(kolicinaKnjige)>=unesenaKolicina and unesenaKolicina > 0):
                #update kolicine
                knjiga = Knjiga.objects.get(pk=IDKnjige)
                knjiga.kolicina = int(knjiga.kolicina) - int(unesenaKolicina) # This is better option (Everything happens on the database side. more safe) => knjiga.kolicina = F('kolicina') - int(unesenaKolicina)
                knjiga.save() # add save method here
                print(knjiga)
                knjiga_forma = KnjigaForma(request.POST, instance = knjiga)
                if knjiga_forma.is_valid(): # add this line
                    knjiga_forma.save()
                forma.save()
                return redirect('pregledPosudbe')
    return render(request, 'unosPosudbe.html', {'forma':forma})
```

## and your delete view

```
from django.http import HttpResponseNotFound

@login_required
def deletePosudbe(request, id):
    try
        data = Posudba.objects.get(id=id)
    except Posudba.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponseNotFound('Resource does not exist!')
    else:
        print('data => ', data)
        print('data.__dict__ => ', data.__dict__)
        data.delete() # you can delete safe way now.
    return redirect('pregledPosudbe')
```

I hope, this code will work. Good luck.

Comment: It does work now, but "knjiga.kolicina" still stays same as before, is it possible to update database field like this or I have to use another way? "knjiga.kolicina = int(knjiga.kolicina) - int(unesenaKolicina)"

Comment: `knjiga.save()` is added.

Comment: Finally!! Thank You!

Comment: You are welcome, but it's preferable to use Django's `F` class object. I updated code and check it. Read more about it in future.

Comment: Yeah, I surely will, can You if You have time check out my update above.

Comment: You added deletePosudbe two times ? why ?

Comment: I am sorry, I misswrote, I just added line "print(data)" to check if I can get ID and Quantity from string and do same as before

Comment: I do not see problem, but i updated my answer and check it.

Comment: Yeah, still same: "AttributeError at /deletePosudbe/22
'Posudba' object has no attribute 'Datum'". Maybe something else is wrong but I don't see what, as it works without print. I can open new post if You want as this is another problem now?

Comment: I think you are showing us wrong code,,, and problem is in another code at all.

Comment: I fixed it, I made mistake in models, thank You one more time for everything